# Select2 issue with adding class to Select2 container in WooCommerce instantiated instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, woocommerce, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

Ok, I have a WordPress/WooCommerce site and I am using Select2 for my select fields, but it seems WooCommerce also uses it for theirs.

I instantiate mine as such:

```
$('select').not('[multiple]').select2({
    minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
    dropdownAutoWidth : true,
});
```

Then I also want to apply a different border colour to fields that already have a value set, so I added this code:

```
$('select').each(function(e) {
    handleSelectSelection($(this));
});

function handleSelectSelections(select) {

    var el = (select.next('.select2').length) ? jQuery(select.data('select2').$container) : select;

    if (select.val() !== "" && select.val() !== null) {
        el.addClass('has-selection');
    } else {
        el.removeClass('has-selection');
    }

}
```

Please note that all code outside the function is inside a `(function($) {` wrapper.

Now, this works fine with the select2 fields my code instantiates, however it doesn't seem to work with the ones WooCommerce instantiates.

I have checked the differences in the `select` fields and I noticed my ones have a `data-select2-id` attribute, whilst the WooCommerce ones do not.

I did some console logging with `jQuery(select.data('select2').$container)` on the WooCommerce ones and it appears quite normal however.

Testing the values returns correct and it even goes inside the section where it attempts to *add* the class, but it just fails to do so.

**Edit:** The interesting thing is it works if you bind it to a `change` event, but not this way.

Any ideas on what is happening here?

Comment: Woocommerce use selectWoo a fork of Select2 see: https://github.com/woocommerce/selectWoo … So may be this could be the problem (not sure).

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Ahh thanks. That's probably it, maybe they forked off an earlier version?